# How can I debug python import not found error?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to configure a Raspberry Pi 3 to run a python script on boot. Following a tutorial I created this script in etc/init.d:

```
#! /bin/sh
# etc/init.d/upload_photos_pir

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     upload_photos_pir
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs &syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Start PIR photo uploads
# Description:      Start PIR photo uploads
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
    start)
      echo "starting pir photos upload"
      # run appl
      /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py
      ;;
    stop)
      echo "stopping pir photos upload"
      # kill app
      killall upload_photos_pir.py
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: etc/init.d/upload_photos_pir {start|stop}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

exit 0
```

running the script produces the following:

```
starting pir photos upload
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 3: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: import: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 4: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: import: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 5: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: import: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 6: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: import: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 7: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: import: not found
from: can't read /var/mail/time
from: can't read /var/mail/datetime
from: can't read /var/mail/picamera
from: can't read /var/mail/subprocess
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 13: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: global: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 16: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: photosHourlyLimit: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 17: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: photosTaken: not found
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: 18: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The script I am trying to start upload_photos_pir.py runs fine from the python shell.

I don't understand why the the imports don't happen as they should. I am new to the Raspberry Pi and python, so there's a lot I am not sure about with respect to paths, file locations etc., so I am guessing the issue is related to using the wrong paths in the `#! /bin/sh` file, but don't know enough to even ask the right question.

Can anyone explain what might not be working, how to debug this issue, or point me in the direction of an explanation?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you `chmod +x upload_photos_pir.py`?  Does it have a `#!/bin/env python` (or similar) at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice above that you invoke your python program as

```
/home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py
```

I am going to bet you do not have a line at the top of this file that looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Which means that your program will be invoked by sh / bash.  These error messages are the ones that bash is printing as it attempts (and fails) to parse your python file.

You can fix this two ways:

- Change your script to invoke with `python /home/pi/upload_photos_pir.py`
- Add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of your file

Comment: Remember to `chmod +x upload_photos_pir.py` if you are adding a shebang.

Comment: it would be `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for python 3.

Comment: @Cireo Thanks very for the reply. I have read about adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the python script. When I try it, I get an another error: /home/pi/upload_photos_pir: not found. However, when I tried the first of your solutions, adding `python` to call, that worked.

Comment: You may have accidentally removed the `.py` when you made the first change, based upon your message `/home/pi/upload_photos_pir: not found`.  It is good practice to put the `#!` at the top of your file anyway =).  Glad it helped

Comment: Alas, the 'killall` does not work either. I get `/home/upload_photo_pir.py: no process found.` even though `ps aux | grep unpload_photos_pir.py does show, if I understand it, a process running as root.

Comment: The comment section is not the right place to follow up.  Read up a bit on killall - in this case the process is python, the filename being executed is simply an argument (e.g. `kill /` won't kill `ls -R /`).